# How to write if statement from SAS to python

Tags: python, sas

I am a SAS user who try to transform SAS code to python version.

I have create SAS code as below and have some issues to apply to python language. Supposed I have data table, which contained fields aging1 to aging60 and I want to create new two fields, named 'life_def' and 'obs_time'. These two fields contained value as 0 and will be changed based on condition from other fields, which are aging1 to aging60.

```
data want;
set have;
array aging_array(*) aging1--aging60;

life_def=0;
obs_time=0;

do i to 60;
     if life_def=0 and aging_array[i] ne . then do;
          if aging_array[i]>=4 then do;
               obs_time=i;
               life_def=1;
               end;
     if aging_array[i]<4 then do;
               obs_time=i;
               end;
           end;
end;

drop i;
run;
```

I have tried to re-create above SAS code into python version but it doesn't work that I though. Below is my code that currently working on.

```
df['life_def']=0
df['obs_time']=0

for i in range(1,lag+1):
    if df['life_def'].all()==0 and pd.notnull(df[df.columns[i+4]].all()):
        condition=df[df.columns[i+4]]>=4
        df['life_def']=np.where(condition, 1, df['life_def'])
        df['obs_time']=np.where(condition, i, df['obs_time'])
```

Supposed df[df.columns[i+4]] is my aging columns in SAS. By using code above, the loop continue when i is increased. However, the logic from SAS provided is stop i at the first time that aging>=4.

For example, if aging7>=4 (first time) life_def will be 1 and obs_time will be 7 and assign the next loop, which is 8.

Thank you!

Comment: I think in this particular case trying to do a 'straight' conversion isn't practical, I suspect there are some python functions that can massively simplify this logic. What is the overall logic, find the first record over 4?

Comment: @Reeza Hi, the logic behind is to count how many time that touch aging >=4 in each loop

Comment: The 2nd block in python is not working? What's the error msg? I see a typo on line 7: there is a bracket `'` too much. --> `if df['aging'+str(i)]>=4:`

Comment: @stallingOne I have edited the code but results doesn't meet with SAS. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Is this a list or a data frame?

Comment: @Reeza it's data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objective is to get the first `aging**x**` column's `x` (per row) that is ge 4. The snippet below would do the same thing.

*Note - I am using python 2.7*

```
mydf['obs_time'] = 0

agingcols_len = len([k for k in mydf.columns.tolist() if 'aging' in k])
rowcnt = mydf['aging1'].fillna(0).count()

for k in xrange(rowcnt):
    isFirst = True
    for i in xrange(1, agingcols_len):
        if isFirst and mydf['aging' + str(i)][k] >= 4:
            mydf['obs_time'][k] = i
            isFirst = False
        elif isFirst and mydf['aging' + str(i)][k] < 4:
            pass
```

I have uploaded the data that I used to test the above. The same can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pr9HEg0HRTS89AU-cIL5IBoTzOWdvDPk).

The snippet iterates over all the `aging**x**`columns (e.g. - `aging1`, `aging2`), and keeps increasing the `obs_time` till it is greater than or equal to 4. This whole thing iterates over the `DataFrame` rows with `k`.

**FYI** - However, this is super slow when you have million rows to loop through.

Comment: FYI - The above python snippet is to mimic the SAS data step as is. There may be other optimized ways of achieving the required output and logic.

Comment: Thanks for sharing I will try this out.